# Converting column values in postgresql from text to smallint throws error

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

[image]

As you can see, the only column thats throwing error here is user_uuid

I want it to have datatype uuid. Previously before loading the data it was of the type object in python.

Simplified problem:

```
ALTER TABLE dim_users
    ALTER COLUMN user_uuid TYPE UUID USING (user_uuid::UUID);
```

ERROR:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "abc"

Comment: 1) The question title is wrong you are not converting to `smallint`, you are converting to `uuid`. 2) This `"abc"` is noy a `uuid` value. 3) This is *Previously before loading the data it was of the type object in python.* is unclear. What type object? **Add answers to the preceding questions **as text update** to the question text.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are indeed `UUID`-compatible, then something like this works:

```
create table foo(a varchar(64));

insert into foo(a) values('A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11');

alter table foo
alter column a type uuid using a::uuid;
```

so in that case your script should work. It will work with nulls as well:

```
create table foo(a varchar(64));

insert into foo(a) values('A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'), (null);


alter table foo
alter column a type uuid using a::uuid;
```

**but it won't work by itself on values that cannot be converted into uuid**:

```
create table foo(a varchar(64));

insert into foo(a) values('A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'), ('b');


alter table foo
alter column a type uuid using a::uuid;
```

so you have some values that cannot be converted into `uuid`. So, we need to determine whether a value is a proper `uuid`, convert it to `uuid` in that case and default to `null` otherwise:

```
create table foo(a varchar(64));

insert into foo(a) values('A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11'), ('b');


alter table foo
alter column a type uuid using case when a ~ E'^[[:xdigit:]]{8}-([[:xdigit:]]{4}-){3}[[:xdigit:]]{12}$' then a::uuid else null end;
```

Nice, is it not?

You are of course well-advised to back up your data before doing this and carefully check the results.